# Node js substract Timestamp

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to substract a timeStamp in node js (google cloud functions).
This is my timestamp:

```
var currentTime = admin.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP.toString();
console.log(currentTime); //1537806936331
```

I would like to get the currentTime - 8 hours.

How can I do that?
(i'm using it with in a cloud function (firebase))

Thanks in advance for the help & effort!

Comment: @matsev OP doesn't want to subtract a date, what OP wants is to substract the timeStamp. Check my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This timestamp `1537806936331` is equal to `Monday, September 24, 2018 7:35:36.331 PM GMT+03:00 DST`. You can find here:

https://www.epochconverter.com/

Therefore try the following:

```
let date = new Date(1537806936331); //Mon Sep 24 2018 19:35:36 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time)
let hours = date.getHours() - 8; //11
```

Check here for more info:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

---

If you want to get the timestamp of the date above then try the following:

```
let date = new Date(1537806936331); //Mon Sep 24 2018 19:35:36 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time) //11
date.setHours(date.getHours() - 8); //11
let timeStamp = Date.parse(date);
console.log(timeStamp); //1537778136000
```

You can use [`Date.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) to get the timestamp.

Comment: Thanks! I understand, but is there a function that will return the same format as this: 1537806936331

Comment: u want to convert date to timestamp?

Comment: yes indeed, i would like to get the same this 1537806936331 minus 8 hours back in that format.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? The timestamp is converted to a date and then u can use getHours which gives you `19` and you substract it

Comment: because I need a timestamp in that format for my database...

Comment: try the update in the answer

Comment: Isn't `date.getTime()` a better way to get the timestamp? `Date.parse()` is for parsing formatted dates.

Comment: @Barmar according to this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse if you give parse() a formatted date then it will return the timestamp for it that's why i used parse(). You can run the code written in the link and then test it here https://www.epochconverter.com/

Comment: But `date` isn't a formatted date, it's a `Date` object. The only reason it works is because the function requires a string argument, and converting a `Date` to a string formats it. So you're formatting it and then parsing it, when you could just use it the way it is.

Comment: @Barmar okay I understand thank you for commenting, so I could have done this then `let date = new Date(1537806936331); 
date.setHours(date.getHours() - 8); 
let timeStamp = date.getTime();
console.log(timeStamp);`

Comment: @Barmar thank you for commenting I really like your answers!

Answer (score 3):

The timestamp you have is the number of milliseconds that have passed since the epoch. This means you can also use a regular subtraction of millisecond to get the timestamp of 8 hours before.

So a simpler version to Peter's (correct) answer is:

```
var currentTime = admin.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;
var eightHoursAgo = currentTime - 8*60*1000;
```

Where `8*60*1000` is the number of milliseconds in 8 hours.